# android textview set height does not work

Tags: android, textview, height

I am trying to create a layout with nested linear layouts and textviews which are placed vertically in a linear layout. They are created programatically. While I can set the height of the linear layout using layout Params I am not able to do this for textview. Using Textview setLayoutParams or setHeight function provides no response. The text is always wrapped around the content (though this is no where mentioned by me in the code). Can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 2):

this code might help you:

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsLayoutExpire = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    TextView txtView=new TextView(this);
    txtView.setLayoutParams(paramsTextViewExpire);
```

LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT: Height

LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT: Width

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help

```
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("Hellow World");
    textView.setHeight(prefered_height_in_pixel);
    this.addView(textView)
```